# Upgrading from XHR-Polling to Websockets in Socket.io 1.0.X results in packets dropping

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, upgrade, polling

I have been working with a problem in Socket.io 1.0.6, where a client randomly does not receive a packet on a given protocol, and randomly does.

I have been running my node application with prefix DEBUG=* and in the browser set the variable localStorage.debug='*'.
It goes as follows:
1. Client emits on 'event'.
2. Server receives on 'event' and emits on 'event'.
3. Client does receive on 'event'/client does not receive on 'event' (randomly).
Debug messages approves this.
I do not get any error messages, just don't receive packets.

My server now runs with this configuration, which works every time:

var io = require('socket.io')(port, { allowUpgrades : false });

Have anyone else experienced problems with upgrading transport protocols in engine.io?

Comment: Update: Is there a problem with Websockets? The packets I seem to lose is pretty large. Should I not send large packets with Websockets? As I understand TCP that should not be a problem.

Comment: Problem solved. There was a crash with the broadcast flag, where the same unique socket inherited the state from an earlier call to a specific room with broadcast, like this:

socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('event');

When I then made a call on another event with the same socket, like this:

socket.emit('my_other_event');

Which was intended back to the sender, it sent to everyone else but the sender, because of the broadcast flag were set.